# How to handle iframes with dynamic ids and a single page containing multiple iframes with id starting with common string using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, iframe, dynamic, selenium-webdriver

A page contains multiple iframes with dynamic ids.

The ids look like this

ext-comp-1005,
ext-comp-1031-.x-border-panel

How can i handle an element present inside one of the iframes?
I got a suggestion to use some thing like this
driver.findElement(By.css("iframe:first-of-type"));

This is not the complete/working code.
Could any 1 explain what does the statement mean or how do you handle this kind of situation?

I can go to each frame present on the page & search for the WebElement, but is there an optimal way?

Current Code:

```
int total = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size();
for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    driver.switchTo().frame(i);
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(("sample xpath")))
        .click();
        break;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("not present in frame " + i);
    } finally {
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can happily switch on to required frame with any locator may be xpath.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//your iframe xpath here")));
```

if you frame is inside any other frame, that means if, your required element is inside innerframe, then first switch to outer frame, then again switch to inner frame.

as you know, below command used to come out off all frames..

```
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

i hope you can figure it out xpath even id is dynamically changing. if you have any difficulty on finding the xpath of frame, then post HTML code. Off-course you can use ClassName and Name directly instead of xpath if they exists.

Thanks